# Slope-stability and subbundle of a line bundle.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I have 2 questions.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve. Let $L$ be a line bundle.

> Why is $L$ slope-stable?

What I need to show is that every non trivial subbundle (in the sense that it is a subsheaf which is a vector bundle in its own right) has strictly smaller slope. So a subbundle can have rank $= 0$ or $1$. The 0 case gives the trivial subbundle. What contradiction does the 1 case give?

> Does the 1 case at all occur? That is, can a line bundle have a proper subbundle which has rank 1?

Comment: This should be fairly direct from the definitions, so please start by including the definition  of a subbundle you're working with.

Comment: I am myself a little confused after looking at other posts of related topic in this site. When defining slope stability do we work with subsheaves which are vector bundles in their own right, or only those subsheaves which are not only vb but their quotient is also vb? It seems that considering the two different definitions give non equivalent definition of slope stability.

Comment: I can't tell you what definition to pick - that's your choice (I think I've seen a question on here about it, but I can't find it right now, so if you can't either maybe you could ask a question about what the definition is "supposed" to be). Once you choose your definition, please edit that in to your question.

Comment: I'd like to come to a conclusion for the naive case ie a subsheaf which is a vb in its own right.

Comment: The subbundle can have rank $1$. For example consider the ideal sheaf of a divisor. This is a line-subbundle $\mathcal O_X(-D) \subset \mathcal O_X$, hence has rank $1$.